# Why does [1,2,3,4][1,2] =3 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]; 
var arr2 = [1,2];
```

`console.log(arr1+arr2);` output is `"1,2,3,41,2"`

`console.log(arr1,arr2);` output is `Array [1, 2, 3, 4] Array [1, 2]`

The output 3 in `console.log([1,2,3,4][1,2]);` What is operation/type in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression:

```
console.log([1,2,3,4][1,2]);
```

the comma in the second set of square brackets is acting as [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

As seen in the MDN docs, the comma operator evaluates each side of the comma and returns the final value.

In this case, we get:

```
console.log([1,2,3,4][2]);
```

Which returns the third value, that being the one at array subscript 2.